# How to generate Google API key in android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am new to android, I have a doubt on how to generate Google API key for maps, I tried so many steps, but it doesn't get any result for me. If You have any idea please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: refer this  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#creating_an_api_project

Comment: Thank you rajeshwaran , i got the key by using above link, its very helped for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try to go through the steps from [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key).